# Spring Boot Actuator - Metrics process.start.time incorrect unix epoch value

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

As per requirement needs to convert unix epoch time returned by /metrics/process.start.time into date.But I am getting below output for /metrics/process.start.time

[image]

value returned by it is not in seconds.It contains E in value.

Please guide how I can get correct unix epoch value here.
Thanks

Comment: It *is* in seconds (plus millis) – `1.633520373166E9` is just an unfortunate notation for `1633520373.166`.

Comment: Thank you @slauth for help. Any standard code available to convert 1.633520373166E9 -> 1633520373.166